# How to get the status code of a shell call?

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7

I have the following command:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(["shutdown", "/m", r"\\<some comp name>", "/s", "/f"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

How can I get the status code of the command, for example if the computer does not exist it will output something along the lines of `<comp name> the entered computer name is not valid... talk to y our admin(53)` what I want to do is get the exit code of the command and if it works output `yes` if it doesn't output `no`, how can I get the status code of the command?

Answer (score 2):

straightforward way, with as a bonus redirection/merge of standard error output (often interesting in the case of an error):

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["shutdown", "/m", r"\\<some comp name>", "/s", "/f"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output = proc.stdout.read()
return_code = proc.wait()
```

(note that I removed the `shell=True` option, useless because you're not using the shell features in your command, keep it that way if you can)

Edit: checked for duplicates for a while before answering, but could not find an exact match/simple example using `Popen` (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=subprocess+get+output+return+code)